# catkin_make error, build files are written in the wrong folder

Tags: catkin-make, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a problem compiling my packages.
When running catkin_make, it crashes with:

```
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/..../catkin_ws/src
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/.../catkin_ws/build"
####
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
Invoking "make" failed
```

Does anybody have any suggestion what the cause could be?

Thank you in advance!

--update--

Hi, I apologize for the little info. I created a catkin work-space as described by the tutorial, I have a src directory in it with the corresponding packages, and the necessary files.  I actually had already everything up and running = I had all my packages compiled and up and running. After a git update and some compilation errors I deleted the build and the devel directories in order to build everything again. In the catkin-workspace I used catkin_make to build the packages. It states that the build directory is .....\build and the src directory is...\src so it has the right structure but than it crashes with the error that it does not find the makefiles etc in ...\build. It actually generated all the makefiles but it copied them in the src folder. I have no idea why :(

Thank you for any help!

--update2--

```
Base path: /home/pr/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/pr/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/pr/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/pr/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/pr/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/pr/catkin_ws/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/pr/catkin_ws/devel -
DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/pr/catkin_ws/install" in "/home/pr/catkin_ws/build"
####
[ ....]
Build files have been written to: /home/pr/catkin_ws/src
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197963/catkin_make-error,-build-files-are-written-in-the-wrong-folder/) by [eo](https://answers.ros.org/users/20892/eo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-11-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-11-21**:
There isn't enough information, how are you invoking `catkin_make`?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-11-23**:
You have certainly diverged from the tutorial since the reference of "/home/..../" is wrong. Please post all exact steps you do starting from the very beginning. Only then we can point you to what might be the problem.

**Comment by [Bhargav](https://answers.ros.org/users/5029/bhargav/) on 2014-11-23**:
Did you do `catkin_init_workspace` in your catkin_ws/src folder? Also `catkin_make` should be executed in catkin_ws folder. Please describe the exact steps followed so that we can know where you went wrong.

**Comment by [eo](https://answers.ros.org/users/20892/eo/) on 2014-11-24**:
Hi,
I have performed catkin_init_workspace in the src directory and also performed catkin_make in the workspace directory. Please see output in the second update of my post. I will  create a new workspace and see if it solves the issue.
thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If files in your ./src folder are right, I don't the operation you take will lead this kind of crash.
Have you ever try to recreate another workspace and build? I think it maybe is a quick way to solve the problem.

---

Originally posted by [sukha](https://answers.ros.org/users/19709/sukha/) with karma: 36 on 2014-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

meanwhile i managed to solve the issue. I cannot tell exactly why the error occured. I had a couple of Makefiles in the src directory which apparently caused the entire mess. I deleted them and everything works as expected.
Thank you for all suggestions!

---

Originally posted by [eo](https://answers.ros.org/users/20892/eo/) with karma: 23 on 2014-11-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kotoko](https://answers.ros.org/users/27417/kotoko/) on 2016-08-09**:
This was my problem also, thanks a bunch!